# Javascript cloneNode innerText does not read <br> as \n

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple table

```
<table id="tbl">
<tr>
<th id='first'>First<br>Name</th>
<th id='last>Last name</th>
</tr>
```

if I run a simple `console.log(document.getElementById("first").innerText)` I got results of "First\nName" which is perfect as I see the full text and the \n for the 
 in the text.

Now if I try to use cloneNode() to get data from the table, the \n is stripped out of the innerText

```
tb = document.getElementById("tbl").cloneNode(true);
mydata = tb.rows;
let el = mydata[0].children;
for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
    my_data = el[j].innerText;
    console.log(my_data);
}
```

This will result with "FirstName" "Last Name"
I really need to see the \n in the innerText but it is being filtered out. How can I do this and get the \n in the innnerText?

Comment: [It seems like the newline only shows up after the element is rendered](https://jsbin.com/remesuj/1/edit?html,js,console,output). Although the `<br/>` tag exists at all times. As a guess, `.innerText` is not very consistent. Usually `.textContent` is more stable. However, that doesn't show a new line at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804438/interesting-conversion-of-br-between-innerhtml-and-innertext