# The innerText of the cloneNode is different from the innerText of the original node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I cloneNode as same as the original one?
I want to get the same innerText result with cloned Node, but it didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello
      World</p>
    <script>
      const p = document.querySelector('p');
      const pCloned = p.cloneNode(true);
      const pText = p.innerText; // Hello World
      const pClonedText = pCloned.innerText; // Hello\n     World
      console.log('pText', pText);
      console.log('pClonedText', pClonedText);
      console.log(pText === pClonedText); // false
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is different? You have a newline in your code... Seems correct

Comment: Not sure why, but `textContent` appears to be the same for both.

Comment: @CBroe I want to use innerText for a normal HTML to text result. but I need to change something on the copied node, so I can't operate the original node, and now the copied node is different from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of this:
[Javascript cloneNode innerText does not read <br> as \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589326/javascript-clonenode-innertext-does-not-read-br-as-n)

better use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` as mentioned in the above question's comments if that fits your purpose. Also check the links mentioned in that post.